# Auth0 spring Boot implementation userId has |

Tags: java, spring-boot, auth0

i currently add auth0 to my Spring Boot api, to handle the security. Now I face the problem, that auth0 is generating userId's with the "|" in it.
In my Spring boot api i have some enpoints that are taking the user id as a pathVariable like
"/user/{userId}". Those request now getting a error bc. of the invalid character | in the header.

```
Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/api/v1/user/service/google-oauth2|114309183689720156358 ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: could you encode it to `\u007c` before creating the url? and then decode it after? That will also help if your users have odd characters like æøå in the user ids

Comment: @JoSSte thanks for this suggestion, this is for sure possible. But is this the best solution to always encode and decode the userId? I mean i can't be the only one facing this problem right? So there should be any other solution or auth0 should change the userId.

Comment: Maybe i can configure spring boot, that | is allowed. But i read some where, that it can be open security issues.

Comment: ok nevermind spring boot decodes it automaticly. Then its a solution. thanks very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encode it to `\u007c` before creating the url.

This approach will also help if your users have odd characters like æøåûü in the user ids